# найти натуральное число n представимое суммой кубов двух натуральных чисел,двумя различными способами

Tags: c++, while, соревнование

Найти натуральное число n представимое суммой кубов двух натуральных чисел двумя разными способами. x^3+y^3,(x<=y).Нельзя использовать мат.библиотеки и выполнить с помощью двух циклов while.

Comment: `#include<iostream> int main() { cout << 1729 << endl; }` - никакой математики и while :)

Comment: Смешно конечно)Но вот такую задачу мне дали)

Comment: Какой вопрос - без попыток решать самостоятельно - такой и ответ...

Comment: пытался перебором ,но там явно одним циклом не обойтись,а препод сказал ,что выполняется ОДНИМ простым циклом while.Реально это вообще ?

Comment: Однако задали задачку... Двумя можно, а вот одним... Вам бы сразу это в условии указать, да тэг "соревнование" поставить :)

Comment: Пхаха,так и сделаю)

Answer (score 2):

А ведь в принципе, ничего сложного... Правда, сейчас опять заминусуют :)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Cube
{
    int a, b, c;
    Cube(int a, int b):a(a),b(b) { c = a*a*a + b*b*b; }
};

bool operator<(const Cube& x, const Cube& y)
{
    return x.c < y.c;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    set<Cube> s;
    int i = 2, j = 1;
    while(true)
    {
        Cube c{i,j};
        auto f = s.find(c);
        if (f != s.end())
        {
            cout << i << "^3 + " << j << "^3 == " << f->a << "^3 + " << f->b << "^3 == " << f->c << endl;
            break;
        }
        s.insert(c);
        if (++j == i) { j = 1; ++i; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Для вас возможно ничего сложного ..но вот это решение ещё больше меня запутало

Comment: Я просто в цикле перебираю пары в порядке возрастания: 1-2, 1-3, 2-3, 1-4, 2-4, 3-4 и так далее, нахожу сумму кубов и запихиваю в контейнер. Предварительно проверяю - там такой суммы нет? Если есть - ура, нашли :) Если нет - идем дальше.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int x1=0, y1 = 1,x2 = 1,y2 = 0;

 while (true)
 {
  x1++;
  y1++;
  if (x1*x1*x1 + y1 *y1 * y1 == 1729)
  {
   cout << x1 << "^3 +" << y1 << "^3\n";

  }
  y2++;
  if (x2*x2*x2 + y2*y2*y2 == 1729)
  {
   cout << x2 << "^3 +" << y2 << "^3\n";
   break;
  }
 }
 
 system("pause");
    return 0;
}
`

Comment: И что? Вы ищете решение, в котором заранее известно, что сумма кубов 1729, что в одной паре есть 1, что во второй разница на 1, и что второе число в первой паре на 1 больше числа во второй... Т.е. ваше решение использует знания об ответе, и в этом смысле ничуть не лучше моего в первом комментарии - вывести готовый ответ...